# converting area element to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner in Javascript/jQuery. Thank you for reading!

EDIT:
Here is a jsfiddle with all of the code (annotated) https://jsfiddle.net/sfs1926/n1sopf79/ 
It does not work, but here is a working example video of what my code does so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N67Bx9jgPFo

The context is: I am trying to model layers of electronics (represented as rectangles) on a graph. There are 10,000 overlapping rectangles (each representing the position of a piece of electronics). I write these area elements in line by line from a text file that contains the coordinates of each rectangle and its title. I associate each area element with its title using an overlay id. My goal: When I mouse over a pixel on the graph, I want to display ALL rectangles associated with that pixel and their overlay id's (to the side, off the graph). So far I am able to do all of this besides displaying the rectangles.

Right now I have a HTML map 'demo' containing many area elements (all rectangles). I want to use jQuery to push each of those area elements into the array elementPositions. This I do successfully below, but with one exception: I want to create the identifier 'element' to be that area element written as a div with css. This is because I want to show and hide rectangles belonging to elementPositions using the .show() method. That is why I am converting the area elements to be divs.

Can someone help me with the syntax for how to do this conversion? I think the reason why no rectangle will 'show' is because I have not set the display or the background attribute of the div, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
            if( $('#demo').length >0 ) { 

                var elementPositions = [];

                $('#demo area').each(function() {
                var offset = this.coords;
                var coordarray = offset.split(",");
                var left = coordarray[0];
                var top = coordarray[1];
                var right = coordarray[2];
                var bottom = coordarray[3];
                var id = this.id;
                var wid = right - left;
                var hei = bottom - top;
                var hoveredElements = [];

                elementPositions.push({ 
                    element: $('<div class="area"></div>')
                        .css({position: 'absolute', left: left, top: top}).
                        width(wid).height(hei), // attempt so far!
                    top: top, 
                    bottom: bottom, 
                    left: left, 
                    right: right, 
                    id: id, 
                });
```

Then I hope to do something like:

```
                $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
                elementPositions.forEach( function(item) {
                    item.element.show();
                });
                }
```

Comment: Please provide relevant html and css. Position absolue requires its parent element to have position: relative, otherwise it will be relative to the initial containing block. Also I cant see where you are appending the elements to the DOM in your code.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my jsfiddle with explanations written as comments. Thank you very much to take your time to help out a beginner!

Comment: Your js fiddle does not work. There are load fail errors for several files. Are they relevant? Also the code in there is different from the example code in your question.

Comment: You are right, it does not work. it requires several extra files to work but I was hoping the annotated comments would be enough for my question. I have also edited my question to include context of my code and what I am trying to achieve. Maybe it could help?

Comment: I attach a youtube video showing what my code does so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N67Bx9jgPFo

Comment: I would suggest creating a working fiddle, with minimum data, say mock a sample the data that comes from the ajax request, eg: a sample of what is in the text file and then use that. It is very hard to just look at that code and figure out how it is meant to work. Its hard to explain too I suppose with just words. Here is an update: https://jsfiddle.net/n1sopf79/4/, But I still need data in there.

Comment: Arathi - does the youtube video help? I can work on creating mock data but it would take me a while.

Comment: I can't look at youtube videos, sorry. I have restricted net access. Please try and make the fiddle work. It should be  fairly easy. Try replacing the script tags with appropriate javascript addons. And mock data as explained above.

Comment: I will try to make it work. Is there a particular difficulty you have in understanding my question above, or is it just generally too hard to follow?

Comment: Its not easy to solve without a working example. Since there could be different things you have got wrong. But hard to say without seeing what it is.

Comment: Yeah I understand, and I am sorry I don't have a better example working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to append your div before show it, append to `body` for example :

```
var elementDiv = $('<div class="area"></div>')
                        .css({position: 'absolute', left: left, top: top}).
                        width(wid).height(hei);
$("body").append(elementDiv );
elementDiv.hide();

elementPositions.push({ 
                    element: elementDiv ,
                    top: top, 
                    bottom: bottom, 
                    left: left, 
                    right: right, 
                    id: id, 
                });
```

Comment: Dear Mostafa- thank you I will give this a try now! so you think it would show even without the 'display' or 'background' CSS attributes?

Comment: you need to set the background to check if it work or just use 'inspect element'

Comment: var elementDiv = $('<div class="area"></div>')
                        .css({position: 'absolute', left: left, top: top, background: 'red'}).
                        width(wid).height(hei);

Comment: Thank you so much!